# c# tooltip backcolor and forecolor are not changing with using method or other ways

Tags: c#, tooltip

I want to use tooltips in my windows forms application. So i created a simple method like this:

```
        public void MyTooltips(Control c, string m, bool b)
        {
            ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
            t.IsBalloon = b;
            t.SetToolTip(c, m);
            t.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
            t.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
```

And i am using it like this: `MyTooltips(combobox1, "If anything, select zero.", true);`
In the usage, tooltip back and fore colors are not changing. Tooltips shown as Windows 7 default tooltip back and fore colors. How can i do this?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTML Renderer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32376/A-Professional-HTML-Renderer-You-Will-Use) can do this. For example:

```
htmlTooltip1.Set(textBox1, "<font color=\"red\">What is tooltip?</font>");
```

Answer (score 4):

From the relevant [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.backcolor.aspx) for the `BackColor` property:

> Unless the ToolTip is owner-drawn, this property is ignored.

If you want to customise the colour of the ToolTip, you will have to set `OwnerDraw` to true and paint the control yourself (using the `Draw` event).

Comment: Thank you. I am striving to creat a method. But i saw, it is hard. May be, i should continue with Window's style :)

Comment: It is generally accepted that you should use the operating system style in preference to your own. You can draw the user's attention to a ToolTip without changing the colours by adding a title and/or icon.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN help is not 100% accurate: BackColor **does** work if you don't enable visual styles: comment out the call to `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in your Main(). But purists would probably advise that you shouldn't do that .

Comment: This is a weird advise. The application looks really ugly like that.

Comment: It's not really advice, I was just pointing out that the MSDN help has an error. And the application does not necessarily look ugly, in some ways it is improved (for example ComboBoxes look better, IMHO). I guess it depends on the application and on which visual style you have chosen.